# Problem bytes to str

Tags: jython

I'm new in jython and I try to convert bytes to str.

do you know how I can do this?
 Thanks

Comment: Why did you remove the input/output from you question? What do you mean by `'bytes'`, `'str'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from array import array

a = array('b', [30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47])
print ', '.join(map(str, a))
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
from array import array

a = array('b', [30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47])

print a.tostring()
print a.tounicode()
```

Comment: the OP removed input/output. [The original expected output was `'30, 31, 32, ..'`](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4756809/1) so `.tostring()` is not appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.join()` with array as a sequence:

```
import array
ar = array.array('b', [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47])
ars = ', '.join(str(x) for x in ar)
print(ars)
```